# Python 3 issues importing multiprocessing with __import__

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-multiprocessing

So the issues that I am currently hitting is with the use of `__import__` and even just the standard import. When importing multiprocessing just the main package it will go through however when I run a simple test to see if everything is working for it. I come across an error, below is the current code that IS NOT working.

```
__import__('multiprocessing')

def my_function():
    print('Hello World')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    processd = multiprocessing.Process(target=my_function)
    processd.start()
    processd.join()
```

it run it will return the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Webserv\Python\MP.py", line 7, in <module>
    processd = multiprocessing.Process(target=my_function)
NameError: name 'multiprocessing' is not defined
```

Is there something I am missing with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__import__` is a function, therefore you need to capture its return value:

```
multiprocessing = __import__('multiprocessing')
```

The standard way is to use the `import` statement:

```
import multiprocessing
```

This is the preferred way. Do programmatic imports only when you really need them. Furthermore, `__import__` should not be used:

> Import a module. Because this function is meant for use by the Python
>   interpreter and not for general use it is better to use
>   `importlib.import_module()` to programmatically import a module.

Comment: yes, however I ended up going with using the `import multiprocessing as mp` as it shortens things up quite a bit..

Comment: Yes, this is a variation of the `import` statement.